# Sql unknown comparisson expression

Tags: sql-server

Today I was looking through an Excel file for a new project and I found out a query with where clause, something like

```
WHERE ((GA145M1.NHSHDT>=? And GA145M1.NHSHDT<=?))
```

I cannot run this in Sql nor can i find anythnig about this.

I want to execute the whole query in an Sql Openquery but it won't work as long as this expression is in there

the error I get is

> OLE DB provider "IBMDA400" for linked server "MACPAC" returned message
>   "SQL0313: Number of host variables not valid. Cause . . . . . :   The
>   number of host variables or entries in an SQLDA or descriptor area
>   specified in either an EXECUTE or OPEN statement is not the same as
>   the number of parameter markers specified in the prepared SQL
>   statement S000001.  If the statement name is *N, the number of host
>   variables or entries in a SQLDA or descriptor area was specified in an
>   OPEN statement and is not the same as the number of host variables
>   specified in the DECLARE CURSOR statement for cursor C000001. Recovery
>   . . . :   Change the number of host variables specified in the USING
>   clause or the number of entries in the SQLDA or descriptor area to
>   equal the number of parameter markers in the prepared SQL statement or
>   the number of host variables in the DECLARE CURSOR statement. 
>   Precompile the program again.".

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: added more info

Comment: Question marks (?) may denote parameter asking, excel thing - not applicable in SQL Server.

Comment: Passing parameters with `?` actually is used in SQL Server, but only if `EXECUTE .. AT` is used to execute a parameterized query on a linked server. `OPENQUERY` does not support parameters and requires setting up an unparameterized query with string concatenation.